# Mysql start fails with Operating System error 13

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have XAMPP on my Ubuntu Lucid system and everything worked fine. But there seems to be some problem now and mysql wouldn't start.

I had tried to recover a few Drupal databases and hence copied the raw files to /opt/lampp/var/mysql folder like all other database folders. And, I guess that could have caused the problem. I am pasting the last few lines of the error log. Someone please help me out.

```
100814 15:17:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
100814 15:17:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100814 15:17:47 [ERROR] Can't open shared library 'libpbxt.so' (errno: 0 API version for STORAGE ENGINE plugin is too different)
100814 15:17:47 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'PBXT' with soname 'libpbxt.so'.
100814 15:17:48  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a directory ownership issue.

```
chown mysql.mysql -R /opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

Should fix it.

The libpbxt error is because of a conflict between your system libraries and the ones bundled with XAMPP, but that is not fatal

Comment: Well, I changed the ownership and now the mysql server gets started. The problem now is that the user can't login. I receive Access denied.

Comment: reset the password. why are you running xampp anyway why not run the packages supplied by ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

My xampp installation on Ubuntu Lucid has the mysql ownership as nobody.root, or for some files root.root. So I don't think the above is correct. I think maybe the user is not aware that lampp executable (`/opt/lampp/lampp start`) must be executed as user `root` :

```
tomtom@bach:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Enter sudo password: <hidden input>[Enter]
```

and now lampp should launch the components of xampp.

xampp for me meant easy integration and meant examples and documentation. I like it.